# Angular i18n don't understand the route when switching languages

Tags: angular, nginx, internationalization, docker-build

I am working with i18n in Angular. I have successfully built 2 folders for each language and started running with Docker.
It works fine with the default language but when switching the language I proceed to edit the URL eg localhost to localhost/en. I got an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'en'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'en'
```

Here is my Nginx config file:

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  localhost;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
            alias   /usr/share/nginx/html/fr/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /fr/index.html;
        }

        location /fr/ {
            alias   /usr/share/nginx/html/fr/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /fr/index.html;
        }

        location /en/ {
            alias   /usr/share/nginx/html/en/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /en/index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have dict directory structure like this after build:

```
/dict
----web
    ----fr
    ----en
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try to remove ths last backslash in location. location /fr

Comment: @KevinZhang I still got that problem ~~.

Comment: Did you reload you nginx?

Comment: Yes I did. I'm really bored with this problem

Comment: What's your build command, you must be set different base-href for each language. Something Like ng build --output-path=dist/fr --prod --bh /fr/
 ng build --output-path=dist/en --prod --bh /en/

Comment: I built with "npx ng build --configuration=en" and "npx ng build --configuration=fr"  command. I also configured "outputPath": "dist/web/<language>/" in angular.json so I already have the directory as described above.

Comment: Take a look at angular doc https://angular.io/guide/i18n#deploy-multiple-locales, I guess it still you build command issues.